# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.readdoang.ui.login_regist_activity.LoginRegistActivity cannot be cast to com

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Hello im new in android

i get error when implementing navigation graph on MVP structure, and i don't know how to solve it, and my question is how to call presenter from view fragment class

this is my fragment class

```
class RegisterFragment : Fragment(), RegisterView.View {

    private lateinit var presenter : RegisterView.Presenter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false)
        buttonAction(root)
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun buttonAction(root: View) {
        val name: String = root.txt_email.text.toString()
        val email: String = root.txt_name.text.toString()
        val password: String = root.txt_password.text.toString()

        presenter = (activity as RegisterView.Presenter?)!!

        root.btnSignUp.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.sendData(name, email, password)
        }

    }

    override fun onDataRegisterComplete(response: User) {
        Log.d("Reponse : ", "$response")
    }

    override fun onDataRegisterFailure(throwable: Throwable) {
        Log.d("Response : ", "$throwable")
    }
}
```

this is my view interface

```
interface RegisterView {
    interface View {
        fun onDataRegisterComplete(response: User)
        fun onDataRegisterFailure(throwable: Throwable)
    }

    interface Presenter {
        fun sendData(email: String, name: String, password: String)
    }
}
```

and this is my presenter

```
class RegisterPresenter(context : Context?) : RegisterView.Presenter {

    private val regist = context as RegisterView.View

    override fun sendData(name: String, email: String, password: String) {

    }

}
```

and i have done nothing yet in presenter

this is my error message from log

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.readdoang.ui.login_regist_activity.LoginRegistActivity cannot be cast to com.example.readdoang.ui.register_activity.RegisterView$Presenter
        at com.example.readdoang.ui.register_activity.RegisterFragment.buttonAction(RegisterFragment.kt:37)
        at com.example.readdoang.ui.register_activity.RegisterFragment.onCreateView(RegisterFragment.kt:24)
```

thanks

Comment: You're casting your Activity to a Presenter. Given that you have some separate `RegisterPresenter` class that isn't an Activity, you should explain what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your class RegisterFragment,override the onCreateView(), in this method you can pass your view(fragment) to presenter like this :

```
presenter =  RegisterPresenter(this)
```

and your presenter should like this :

```
class RegisterPresenter(internal val view: RegisterView.View) : RegisterView.Presenter
```

Comment: after this change, in your presenter class, you can directly use the variable view. instead of  this    
 private val regist = context as RegisterView.View

Comment: if it's passing from the activity then **this** is passed to presenter like
presenter = RegisterPresenter(this)

from the fragment, instead of passing **this** to  presenter, getActivity()/getContext() method is used.